# Select odd checkboxes

Tags: javascript

Select odd check boxes please help me with the code

```
for(let i=0;i<8;i++){
if(i%2==1){
document.querySelector(“ul.todo-list > li:nth-child(i) input.toggle”).click()
}
}
```

Comment: What is your HTML?

Comment: No need fo a loop, you can use `li:nth-child(even)` or `li:nth-child(odd)` to target even or odd elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `li:nth-child(odd)` then set the checked attribute to true for those selected checkboxes.

This is an example:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('ul.todo-list > li:nth-child(odd) input[type="checkbox"]');
for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++){
    elements[i].checked = true;
}
```

```html
<ul class="todo-list">
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" />
    </li>
</ul>
```